# Compare an object to null in Java

Tags: java, object, null, compare

I am trying to verify whether an object is `null` or not, using this syntax:

```
void renderSearch(Customer c) {
    System.out.println("search customer rendering>...");
    try {
        if (!c.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("search customer  found...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("search customer not found...");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("search customer rendering error: "
                + e.getMessage() + "-" + e.getClass());
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> search customer rendering error: null
> class java.lang.NullPointerException

I thought that I was considering this possibility with my **if** and **else** statement.

Comment: plus. if and else is not called a loop. its a condition

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're not comparing the objects themselves, you're comparing their references.

Try

```
c != null
```

in your **if** statement.

Answer (score 12):

```
!c.equals(null)
```

That line is calling the equals method on c, and if c is null then you'll get that error because you can't call any methods on null.
Instead you should be using

```
c != null
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `c == null`, since you're comparing **references**, not objects.

Answer (score 8):

Use c==null

The equals method (usually) expects an argument of type customer, and may be calling some methods on the object. If that object is null you will get the NullPointerException.

Also c might be null and c.equals call could be throwing the exception regardless of the object passed

Answer (score 3):

Most likely Object c is null in this case.

You might want to override the default implementation of equals for Customer in case you need to behave it differently.

Also make sure passed object is not null before invoking the functions on it.

Answer (score -3):

The reality is that when c is null, you are trying to do null.equals so this generates an exception. The correct way to do that comparison is "null".equals(c).

Answer (score -4):

if C object having null value then following statement used to compare null value:

```
if (c.toString() == null) {

    System.out.println("hello execute statement");

}
```

Comment: Nope. `c` itself is null, so you'd get a NullPointerException.