# My Zombie won't find itself.

Tags: java, android, imageview, runnable

That sounds extremely philosophical doesn't it?

Anyways, I have a rather complex problem.

My main_activity class gathers all of the Zombies like so:

```
//Testing Runnable (used to compare the first zombie with the player)
private Runnable updateLocations = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while(true) {
                image_player.getLocationInWindow(pLoc);
                Zombie zoms = zombieCollection.next();
                if(!zoms.equals(null)){
                    zoms.getZombieImage().getLocationInWindow(zLoc);
                }
                System.out.println("Zombie: x = " + zLoc[0] + "; y = " + zLoc[1]);
                System.out.println("Player: x = " + pLoc[0] + "; y = " + pLoc[1]);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

My zombie class gathers information like so:

```
public class Zombie{

float X, Y;
int Width, Height;
Direction fdirc;
ImageView zImage;
Player player;

boolean dead;
int[] zLoc;


public Zombie(ImageView zImage, Player player){
    zLoc = new int[2];
    zImage.getLocationOnScreen(zLoc);

    this.zImage = zImage;
    this.X = zLoc[0];
    this.Y = zLoc[1];
    this.Width = zImage.getWidth();
    this.Height = zImage.getHeight();
    this.fdirc = Direction.EAST;
    this.player = player;
    this.dead = false;

    Thread thread = new Thread(this.startZombieChase);
    thread.start();
}

public ImageView getZombieImage(){
    return zImage;
}
private Runnable startZombieChase = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!dead) {
                moveTowardsPlayer();

                Thread.sleep(10);
                updateZombie.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
private Handler updateZombie = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        /** Because the zombie should always be on top! **/
        zImage.getLocationOnScreen(zLoc);
        zImage.bringToFront();
        zImage.setX(X);
        zImage.setY(Y);

    }
};

private void moveTowardsPlayer(){
    int player_x = player.getPosition()[0];
    int player_y = player.getPosition()[1];

    l("Where is it in zombie class : player - " + player_x + " " + player_y + "zombie  - " + X + " " + Y);

    float compareX = player_x - (int)X;
    float compareY = player_y - (int)Y;



    // Y is closer, so we're moving horizontally.
    if(Math.abs(compareX) < Math.abs(compareY)){
        //Moving North
        if(player_y > Y){
            Y+=1;
        }
        //Moving South
        else if(player_y < Y){
            Y-=1;
        }
    }
    // X is closer, so we're moving vertically.
    else{
        //Moving East
        if(player_x > X){
            X+=1;
        }
        //Moving West
        else if(player_x < X){
            X-=1;
        }

    }
}
public void l(Object string){
    System.out.println("Log - " + string);
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it will move relative to a number (So, it does move relative to something) but, not the correct thing.

[image: a busy cat]

logcat tells me this:

- Where is it in zombie class: **player** - 750 451 **zombie**  - 750 451
- Where it is in main_activity: **player** - 750 451 **zombie**  - 792 619

Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
The entire project is located [here](https://github.com/sheepiiHD/ZombieDefence/tree/master/app/src/main/java/net/battleplugins/msutton/DungeonsAhoy).

Comment: First of all `!zoms.equals(null)` will always return `true` or fail with a NPE.

Comment: Yes.... [it will](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994430/compare-an-object-to-null)...

Comment: A ZombieCollection can have 0 Zombie objects in it, therefore zCollection.next() would return null.

Comment: Maybe, but `zoms.equals(null)` either fails with an exception, or returns `false`. So `!zoms.equals(null)` either fails with an exception, or returns `true`. That is not how things are compared to `null`, and you can refer to the link above.

Comment: Despite all of this, the Zombie isn't null, and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: [mcve] - stop thinking about zombies. This is a problem that revolves around a few variables, numbers, maybe threads.

Comment: I am 100% aware of that, if you're talking to me. That's what I'm trying to tell them. It has nothing to do with the "nullness" of the Zombie. That's not where the problem lies. If it ALWAYS returns true, then it will cast the function ANYWAYS. Which means it will update the location regardless of a NPE. The problem I'm having is with the variables, numbers, and threads.

Comment: Guess this will go to bounty in 2 days.

Comment: Adding Bounty will give to more downvotes bdw you are not understanding the programming logic and being rude to member of SO

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but downvotes are pixels that don't mean anything to me. I understand that I may have approached it inappropriately, and I apologize. People are trying to "polish my code". That's great, but it doesn't answer my question and that's what I need. I need to know why there are two different references, and no one is helping me answer that question.

Comment: Yep sure thing that gamification got the heads of so many here . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zombies that moves away from the Brainz, must be an ill Zombie. We can't have that, now can we?

To have a function that moves the Zombie towards the non-zombie, you use a function, but that function makes use of variables that are not arguments, and there fore hard to find out where they come from. I'd go with something like this: (this is a bit verbose, but clearly shows what is happening)

```
/*
 * Function to update the position of the Zombie, aka walk to the Player.
 * @player_pos       - Where's the Brainz at?
 * @zombie_pos       - Where am I?
 * Might want to build it overloaded with an option for the speed.
 *
 * @return           - We return the new Zombie pos.
 */
private double [] moveTowardsPlayer(double [] player_pos, double [] zombie_pos) {
    // To make sure we don't override the old position, we copy values. (Java stuff)
    double [] player_pos_old = player_pos.clone();
    double [] zombie_pos_old = zombie_pos.clone();

    // Let's get the new X pos for the Zombie
    double left_or_right = player_pos_old[0] - zombie_pos_old[0]; // pos number is right, neg is left
    double zombie_pos_new_x;
    if (left_or_right > 0) { // Right
        zombie_pos_new_x = player_pos_old[0] + zombie_speed;
    } else { // Left - this way we make sure we are always getting nearer to the Brainz.
        zombie_pos_new_x = player_pos_old[0] - zombie_speed;
    }

     // TODO: do the same for the Y pos.

    // Bring it together
    double [] zombie_pos_new = {zombie_pos_new_x, zombie_pos_new_y};

    // One step closer to the Brainz!
    return zombie_pos_new;
}
```

And use like:

```
double [] zombie_pos = moveTowardsPlayer([2, 2], [5, 4]);
this.X = zombie_pos[0]; // I'd advice to keep these together as one var.
this.Y = zombie_pos[1]; // But it's your game.
```

And then figure out when the Zombie gets the Brainz (or the Bullet)

Answer (score 3):

this here is not correct:

```
if(!zoms.equals(null)){
```

if you are trying to check that zoms is not pointing to a null reference then do

```
if(zoms != null ){
```

Comment: I have changed this, it does not solve the issue. Nor can I think how it would solve the issue. 

I'm checking references to the position, the issue is not checking whether or not it's null. I'm not getting NPEs.

Comment: even if it does not fix your problem, it was wrong, so do what ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ suggested

Comment: I'm not asking you to critic my programming. I'm asking for help for my problem. This right here doesn't fix my problem. If it doesn't fix my problem, then why would it be an answer? It's not an answer to my question, therefore it's purposeless to me.

Comment: @sheepiiHD Maybe appreciate the fact that people are trying to help you for FREE? :)

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but you need to understand where I am coming from. This answer doesn't solve my question, it's critique. It's not a solution, it doesn't help me, and frankly even if I did implement this, which I did, I'd still be back at square one with the same problem I had before. I'm not asking someone to polish my code. I have come to the realization that this part is incorrect, but again: This - does - not - help - me. So, how are they trying to help me for free if they're not helping me at all?

Comment: Why on Earth was this flagged as Very Low Quality??? I just don't get it.